# How to convert decimal NCR to Unicode character(C++)

Tags: c++, unicode

I have to compare 2 same Chinese language string, but when I fetch one string in my code i get in DECIMAL NCR value i.e., `&#19979;&#19968;&#27493;(n)` 
I want to convert this decimal value to UNICODE CHARACTER to get "下一步(n)" 
How can I convert this decimal to unicode. 
Used : MultiByteToWideChar : not working

Comment: You might want to start with showing us your code so far. That said, does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461499/decimal-to-unicode-char-in-c help you?

Comment: Parse the decimal digits into a suitable unsigned integer variable. The value of the variable will then be the UNICODE character code.

Comment: 1) Not clear what you are doing/wanting. 2) Unicode are encodings, not datatypes. 3) Read [ask], provide all information required. 4) Don't spam tags!

Comment: @Aziuth : I'm working on huge software application how I can display full  1 Lac line of code here

Comment: You really should take the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). When you ask a question on SO, it's your job to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The unicode code point has no direct representation in C++. Generally it is stored in 32-bit integer, but it needs to be converted to it.
To convert single NCR you can simply drop all non-numeric symbols in it and parse as integer with base 10 in your case (with `atoi` for example).
The question now is what is the second format. If it is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description), UTF-32 then, you need to decode it properly. And if it is NCR then you have no problem - compare them even without decoding.

Note. that UTF-8 is not wchar, it is variable-length encoding compatible with ASCII and stored in 8-bit [code units](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#code_unit) called [octets](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#octet) or [bytes](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#byte). UTF-16 is not a wchar, it is also a variable-length encoding stored in 16-bit code units (which may have same size as wchar).

Comment: Dropping all non-numeric characters in `&#19979;&#19968;&#27493;` would get you `199791996827493`. I understand what you intended, but that's not what you wrote ;). What's a slightly bigger mistake is "16 bit code units which happen to be the same size as `wchar_t`.". The only thing you can assume about `wchar_t` is that it's at least 8 bits. 16 bits is common (Windows), but so is 32 bits (OSX, Linux).

Comment: So can i convert using MultiByteToWideChar  from decimal NCR to utf8

Comment: @viveksingh no, NCR is not an encoding. Transform it to code points and then transform both strings to any common format.

Comment: int u8_wc_toutf8(char *dest, u_int32_t ch)<br>
{
    if (ch < 0x80) {
        dest[0] = (char)ch;
        return 1;}
    if (ch < 0x800) {dest[0] = (ch>>6) | 0xC0;
        dest[1] = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        return 2;}
    if (ch < 0x10000) {dest[0] = (ch>>12) | 0xE0;
        dest[1] = ((ch>>6) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        dest[2] = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        return 3;
    }
    if (ch < 0x110000) {dest[0] = (ch>>18) | 0xF0;
        dest[1] = ((ch>>12) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        dest[2] = ((ch>>6) & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        dest[3] = (ch & 0x3F) | 0x80;
        return 4;}return 0;
}

Comment: @viveksingh yes, this looks like utf-8 converter